# Erro no JavaScript ao abrir página - Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, xhtml

Quando abro a página ela quebra e quando abro o console do browser aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

Quando vejo o código no console ele aparece desse jeito:

```
if (linhaAnterior$.size() &gt; 0) {}
```

Mas o meu código na verdade está assim:

```
if (linhaAnterior$.size() > 0) {}
```

Tenho outros `if`s nesse código mas somente neste ocorre essa mudança quando abro a página.

Comment: A tua tag de `<script/>` deveria conter o atributo  `type="text/javascript"`! Outra coisa, quem trata do output para o navegador? Parece que os `>` estão a ser convertidos para a sua entidade HTML...

Comment: Eu coloquei o atributo porém a mensagem continua do mesmo jeito

Comment: O atributo foi uma observação para evitares problemas, não propriamente "a" solução! A pergunta que te fiz é que pode ajudar-me a mim a ajudar-te a ti :) _(ver o meu comentário anterior)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você está usando XHTML, é necessário encapsular o código javascript com o CDATA, conforme o trecho abaixo:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
        ...
    // ]]>
    </script>
```

No entanto, é recomendável separar o código javascript em outro arquivo:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/pasta/script.js"></script>
```

Para saber mais, veja http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML.

Comment: Então, eu primeiramente tinha colocado o código javascript dessa forma mas o erro continua do mesmo jeito.